# Error: while using devtool="source-map" option in webpack config version 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-config

I am getting this error while using "source-map" as value to the devtool option in webpack configurations but while using "eval" it works (but I don't want "eval"). It could be a chance that asset can be undefined or not an array. I am new to webpack, could anyone please help me with suggestions like what could be the possibility here?

```
sourceMap = /** @type {SourceMap} */ (asset.map(options));
                                                                ^
    
    TypeError: asset.map is not a function
        at getTaskForFile (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:82:47)
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:269:22
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:91:34
        at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/cache/MemoryCachePlugin.js:45:13)
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:91:19
        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:17:1)
        at Cache.get (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:18)
        at ItemCacheFacade.get (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:117:15)
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:220:18
        at arrayEach (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2405:9)
        at Object.each (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2846:9)
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:204:15
        at fn (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:404:9)
        at _next1 (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:19:1)
        at eval (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:33:1)
        at eval (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
        at /Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:397:10
        at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:5:1)
        at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
        at fn (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:381:45)
        at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:29:1)
        at eval (eval at create (/Users/Desktop/lib-webpack/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
```

Comment: Could anyone help me, what is the asset is referring to here ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because I was using the incorrect format of asset's source object, I need to modify chunk later because I was using white labelling of css.

earlier in webpack 4 =>

```
assets[filename] = {
    source: function() {
        return result.css;
    },
    size: function() {
        return result.css.length;
    },
};
```

earlier in webpack 5 =>

```
assets[filename] = new webpack.sources.RawSource(result.css.toString());
```

Comment: where webpack is -->     apply(compiler) {

        const { webpack } = compiler;